# Having difficulty publishing a custom template for the Print Widget within the Experience Builder

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-experience-builder, print-templates

I have been tasked with finding a way to use custom templates within the ArcGIS Online Experience builder. The default templates within the Print Widget don't allow for the level of customization that we are seeking, so I've been following [this guide](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/tutorial-publish-additional-layouts-for-printing-with-arcgis-pro.htm) as it seems as though the solution is to create templates and then somehow import them within the Print Widget by adding a new "printing utility" via URL:

[image]

I have been following the guide above, having first prepared two layouts that I would like to use separately within the Print Widget, which differ from the default templates in that they are square, not A4 or A3, and have several unique map elements, such as a legend that is on the map and as well as an inset map.

I am now at the section entitled "Publish a print service to ArcGIS Enterprise portal to enable reports" but on step 7 it just says "Publish your templates as a Print service" without any sort of direction on how to do so.
Have I skipped a step?
More importantly, am I going about this in the right way? It seems so simple but for some reason this process has been a little nebulous.

Comment: Do you have an ArcGIS Enterprise subscription? Or are you using ArcGIS Online. If the latter, you will not be able to complete this process, as publishing a printing service requires an active instance of Arc Server.

Comment: That must be it. I didn't realize we needed an Enterprise subscription. Thank you